# Can a character choose to cease being a willing target of a spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

*Foresight, Barkskin* and *Mage Armor* are examples of spells which require consent in order to function.

Could you revoke this consent at a later time of your own choosing in order to end the spell early?

Answer (score 14):

**No - and often the spellcaster can't dismiss it either**

In 5e there are no rules-as-written regarding the target of spell (beneficial or otherwise) ending it early.

However, in the case of a spell that requires **active concentration** (such as [*Barkskin*](http://5thsrd.org/spellcasting/spells/barkskin/#barkskin)), it can be dismissed by the caster as a free action:

*PHB*, page 203:

> **Concentration**
>
> If a spell must be maintained with concentration, that fact appears in
>   its Duration entry, and the spell specifies how long you can
>   concentrate on it. **You can end concentration at any time (no action
>   required)**.

Therefore in combat (assuming the DM allows it), the recipient of a concentration-based spell might be able to call out a short command to the caster and have them drop the spell - all without using an action. The DM might even rule that this can be done outside of either the caster's or the recipient's turns.

Spells that **don't use concentration**, however (like [*Foresight*](http://5thsrd.org/spellcasting/spells/foresight/)), cannot be dismissed early, even by the spellcaster, unless otherwise stated. From the article [The Rules of Spellcasting](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-spellcasting) on the Wizards website:

> **CAN A SPELLCASTER DISMISS A SPELL AFTER CASTING IT?**
>
> You can’t normally dismiss a spell that you cast unless (a) its description says
>   you can or (b) it requires concentration and you decide to end your
>   concentration on it. Otherwise, a spell’s magic is unleashed on the
>   environment, and if you want to end it, you need to cast dispel magic
>   on it.

Given that even the caster cannot end a spell like this early, it could well be ruled that the recipient cannot either.

Comment: Related: [Are non-concentration spells dismissable?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/39679/are-non-concentration-spells-dismissable)

Comment: But being unwilling does not make you an invalid target? As in this question: [How does wild shape interact with dominate beast?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/96838/15469)

Answer (score 9):

By RAW, consent is needed only for the activation of the spell. It is not mentioned that this consent must persist. Therefore, the spell would last independently from the target's will. If there are conditions other than concentration and duration that affect the duration of a spell, they are always mentioned.

Comment: I like the clear cut nature of the answer, but can you give an example of how this is RAW? A quote from the PHB perhaps?