# Can I dismiss an ongoing spell that was cast on me if I decide to be unwilling later?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

With spells like Water Walk, with a duration of one hour, if I have been willing at the moment of casting it, (I am not the caster), and then I decide to be unwilling, does that make me an invalid target and finish the spell on me? [This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/96838/15469) about the interaction between charm beast and the druid reverting to human to end it got me confused about this particular case.

Comment: Yeah, but there is no mention of the druid dilemma in that question, that's why I did it here. Is that valid?

Comment: it all boils down to: Does the linked question's answers answer your question? If yes, it's a duplicate. If no, edit your question to say why not?