# Do the effects spells like Freedom of Movement or Foresight continue to affect a player if they Polymorph, Shapechange, or Wild Shape into a new form?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, druid, polymorph

Do the effects if spells like Freedom of Movement or Foresight continue to affect a player if they Polymorph or Shapechange into a new form in 5th edition DnD?

Hello, as stated above I am wondering if you still retain the benefits of buff spells such as those mentioned above when you change forms through means like Polymorph, Shapechange, Wild Shape, and the more recent addition Potion of Dragon's Majesty.

I am now a level 17 Druid and it would be pretty amazing to be in a dragon form while retaining those spell effects.

Comment: Related: [Does Barkskin cast before Wild Shaping apply to your beast form?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63352/does-barkskin-cast-before-wild-shaping-apply-to-your-beast-form)

Comment: Related: "[Can Polymorph end spells that require the target to be humanoid?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103845)" and "[If a spellcaster casts the Antipathy spell on themself and then True Polymorphs into something else, is the effect of Antipathy still active?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/193135)"

Comment: And another one "[Does an Enlarge/Reduce spell on a druid affect the beast form if the druid Wild-Shapes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/63018)"

Comment: Might be a good case for a signpost question, that resolves this in general, like "How do spells with  ongoing effects work with wild shape?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You keep the effects

There doesn't seem to be anything in the rules that prevents you from keeping any ongoing magical effect your character has.

Moreover, let's think about this another way : if transforming could remove all magical effects on your character, you wouldn't ever really need to use spells that remove negative effects, such as *Greater Restoration*. So it also makes sense from a balance standpoint that transforming wouldn't remove magical effects.

In the case of *Wild Shape* (I couldn't find anything similar for the other transformation spells, but feel free to comment it if I missed it and I'll edit this), you can even keep up your own concentration spell, if you're using one to buff yourself, as the rules text for it mentions the following :

> Transforming doesn't break your concentration on a spell you've already cast, however, or prevent you from taking actions that are part of a spell, such as *call lightning*, that you've already cast.

Answer (score -2):

### There are no hidden rules

Is there a rule that says these effects stop if you Wildshape, either in the spells or Wildshape? No? So, they don't.

Comment: I know this is something the book says, but it really isn't entirely true. If the rules were obvious this site would have far less questions.