# Can Polymorph + Awaken give any creature intelligence and language?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph

If you cast *Polymorph* on a non beast creature then cast *Awaken* on their beast form how much carries over after polymorph ends?

Polymorph does not give any explicit information on what happens to your statistics when the polymorph ends:

> The transformation lasts for the duration, or [drops to 0 hp]. [...] The target's game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the chosen beast.  (Basic Rules, pg. 266)

So this leaves ambiguity when game statistics are altered during polymorph,

The charm effect of Awaken seems pretty clear from the [logic shown here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96836/how-does-wild-shape-interact-with-dominate-beast) and reinforced by the specific wording referring to the target as *a beast or plant* during effects and a *creature* afterwards:

> The awakened **beast or plant** is charmed by you [longer than polymorph.] When the charmed condition ends, the awakened **creature** chooses [...] (Basic Rules, pg. 216)

The other two effects of awakening (other than making a plant mobile) are less clear-cut:

> The target gains an Intelligence of 10. The target also gains the ability to speak one language you know.  (Basic Rules, pg. 216)

I would guess the modification to intelligence would apply to the beast's stats and therefore end with polymorph.

[Language has been classified](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71106/is-language-tied-to-statistics-ability-scores-and-or-skill-proficiencies-accor) as being independent of creature statistics and act more as the character's experience. I'd argue the experience of a stranger turning you into a mouse, then gifting you the ability - as a mouse - to speak a language you have never used before would be an experience you couldn't lose I'm not sure if the language and intelligence granted from awakening should remain linked.

---

These are two examples I can see this having significant impact on my campaign:

1. Meet an NPC I don't share a language with, Polymorph them then Awaken their beast form so they can speak my language. Can I now communicate with them when they turn back?  If their original intelligence was higher then 10 is it reduced to 10?
2. Say I use *find familiar* to get an owl (classified as a fey)
   familiar, then polymorph it to an owl (classified as a beast) so my
   druid friend can cast Awaken on it, does my familiar keep an intelligence of 10 and/or the ability to speak?

So after reverting from an awoken polymorphed state would you keep the 10 intelligence and a new language, only the new language, or not keep either?

Comment: You are aware that Polymorph's maximum duration is 1 hour and Awaken's casting time is 8 hours? Unless you have a way around that, this'll never come up.

Comment: Polymorph and Awaken can be cast by separate characters. You can use _contingency_ to trigger awaken the moment you became a beast or have a magic item that stores the spell.

Comment: Or perhaps in a previous session when the original intended target for Awaken ran off during the casting time the DM ruled that once the casting time completed the gemstone has a few minutes to be touched to a beast to activate and the players are now exploiting that time to cast polymorph and I don't particularly want to stop them ;)

Comment: @Erik Or you could just wish to Awaken.

Comment: @Erik Or consider the [staff of the woodlands](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/965489668434219008) which allows you to cast the awaken spell as an action.

Comment: @Erik Aside from all the other suggestions: Nothing in the Awaken spell states that the target of the spell has to be preset during the whole casting time. You only have to touch it at the end of the 8 hours.

Answer (score 13):

### Oh geez.

Usually I summarize the answers up top here but this is a mess.

From *[Polymorph](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/spells/polymorph.htm)*:

> The target’s game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the chosen beast.

So a *polymorphed* character *is* a beast for all game purposes, unless they specify they exclude shapechanged targets or targets under spell effects.  Awaken says:

> you touch a Huge or smaller beast or plant. The target must have either no Intelligence score or an Intelligence of 3 or less. The target gains an Intelligence of 10. The target also gains the ability to speak one language you know.

Awaken doesn't care about the conditions of the beast except insofar as it is a) Huge or smaller and b) has an Intelligence of 3 or less.  The *polymorphed* character meets both those requirements.  But [Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/736269988885995521) has previously ruled that no longer being a valid target could prematurely end a spell effect -- does *Awaken* end *Polymorph*?

***No,*** because the beast form isn't the target condition of *Polymorph*, it's the effect.  The target condition is being "a creature," which the creature still is.  (Although this elucidates a problem with Crawford's ruling in general, since if the target was "a humanoid," *Polymorph* would never work at all.  It would stop being a valid target as soon as the spell took effect.)

So with all that out of the way -- and assuming the DM has allowed Awaken to be cast in such a way that it overlaps with the duration of *Polymorph* -- what happens in the example case in the question?

1. The character is transformed into a valid beast, the form of which is chosen to be Huge or smaller and have an Intelligence of 3 or less.
2. The beast is *Awakened*, giving it an Intelligence score of 10 and a language known to the caster of *Awaken*.
3. *Polymorph* expires or is dismissed, reverting the character back to their original form.

Easy enough... except for all the unanswered questions.

#### What happens to the character's Intelligence?

Well -- *Polymorph* never explicitly specifies what happens to *any* of the character's ability scores when they revert.  It wouldn't be ruled out by the spell description alone that the character's lowered ability scores are permanent... but that doesn't seem to accord with the spell's intent or level.  Instead, the usual assumption is that the character *regains the ability scores they had before being *Polymorphed*, which in this case, would replace their Intelligence of 10 with whatever it was before the *Polymorph.*  Even if it's lower.  Poor Algernon.

#### What about the language they gained?

Well... again, the common assumption is that all proficiencies, abilities, etc the beast may have had, like Stealth or natural AC, are lost when the character reverts.  In this case, the language was a property of the Awakened beast form.  Unfortunately -- that's gone too.

#### What about the 30-day *charm* effect?

...That isn't an attribute or ability of the beast, it's an ongoing effect from an Instantaneous spell.  We've got no reason to believe that *ongoing* effects end when *Polymorph* ends, only the permanent/innate aspects of the beast form  or maintained spells for which the character is no longer a valid target.  Neither condition applies, so... they're still charmed for 30 days.

#### Would the character be *Awakened* if *Polymorphed* back into their beast form?

I have no idea.

Let's be honest: *Awaken* is a mess and *Polymorph* isn't much better.  The DM would have to decide if it's somehow "the same" beast form or if each instance of *Polymorph* creates a new beast form.  Polymorph's "choice" effect and limitations on the target suggest the latter, but c'mon.  The spell doesn't even clearly specify whether or not the target regains their own mental attribute scores.

Comment: "the language was a property of the Awakened beast form." makes a lot of sense to me, I am now reinterpreting _gains the ability to speak a language_ as a physical change in the beast rather than _gains a fundamental lasting understanding of a language_.  I find your interpretation of the charm staying interesting though, this would mean with a Staff of the Woodlands you could put a creature under a similar effect of _Geas_ in two turns without needing for it to understand your language.

Comment: *[Staff of the Woodlands](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicItemsAToZ.htm#staffOfTheWoodlands)* doesn't have that effect afaik, but if it did, and if it was only valid against beasts, Crawford's ruling about targets would apply.  Unlike *Awaken*, *Geas* has a non-Instantaneous duration.  *Awaken* only works this way because the 5th ed spells are mostly poorly written.

Comment: Ah, you didn't literally mean *Geas,* but Crawford's ruling about the staff.  Well... yeah.  Unless the *charm*  effect can be broken somehow, it totally works with RAW.

Comment: On the matter of the int and the language... it depends on whether it's an instantaneous alteration fo the beast, in which case it goes away when the polymorph does, or whether it's a permanent magical effect, in which case it should still hand around.  After all, changing back from Wild Shape doesn't let a druid just discard curses and magical diseases, right?  On the other hand, "*gains* an intelligence of 10" suggests that it might not reduce their int if said int was naturally higher.

Answer (score 8):

The legitimate target of Awaken is a "beast or plant".

While polymorphed, the creature is a legitimate target and Awaken works. When the polymorph ends, the creature is no longer a valid target and [Sage Advice](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/736269988885995521) tells us that no longer being a valid target ends the effect.

> @Jeremy [Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/736269988885995521) In #DnD, the exceptional trumps the general. (No longer being a valid target trumps condition carryover.)
>
> @Mazoshi1987 Replying to @JeremyECrawford So a druid under the effect of Dominate Beast reverts and is still dominated that makes perfect sense
>   11:56 AM - 27 May 2016

Comment: I can understand that in the context of a spell that has concentration or continues to target a creature.  But when the effect has a duration of instantaneous is that advice still hold? Like is the target required to remain a valid target for the lasting effects to stay after the normal duration of the spell? Does that mean that if an awoken creature is polymorphed into a non beast do they immediately stop being awoken even when turning back?

Comment: Yes, it applies to instantaneous effects

Comment: Ok but by that logic wouldn't spells like _animate dead_ completely cease to function? It targets a pile of bones which immediately stops being a pile of bones upon casting, it's no longer a valid target for the spell so it is cancelled?  Or if a spell [targets a willing creature](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/83894/can-a-character-choose-to-cease-being-a-willing-target-of-a-spell) it could cancel the spell later by being unwilling which contradicts the accepted answer there.  I'm not convinced at least the way you are currently presenting it that that's the answer.

Comment: There is no indication that Crawford's ruling includes instantaneous effects.