# Can you end your own spell prematurely?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, duration

Can you end your own spell prematurely?

My question is about spells in general, but in case an example is needed: Let’s say a ranger casts *[spike growth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spike-growth)* (up to 10 minutes), then realizes it is useless since the enemy is able to fly. Can they end the spell prematurely?

Comment: Related: [When exactly can a caster stop concentrating on a spell?](/questions/139537)

Comment: Related question about the D&D Next Playtest: [Are non-concentration spells dismissable?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/39679/are-non-concentration-spells-dismissable)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Concentration spells can be dispelled at will

Simply dropping concentration (which takes no action, per the rules on [concentration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Concentration)) ends the spell prematurely, unless the spell description overrides what happens when concentration ends (as *[conjure elemental](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-elemental)* does).

If the spell is *not* a concentration spell, you can end it early if the spell description says so, but there is no general rule allowing non-concentration spells to be ended early. (Note that the [Duration section of the spellcasting rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Duration) does not mention being able to end non-concentration spells early.)

The Sage Advice Compendium is an official FAQ document for Dungeons and Dragons, fifth Edition. You can check out version 2.3 [here](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) for free. On page 13, this specific question is answered as well:

> #### Can a spellcaster dismiss a spell after casting it?
>
> You can’t normally dismiss a spell that you cast unless (a) its
> description says you can or (b) it requires concentration
> and you decide to end your concentration on it. Otherwise,
> a spell’s magic is unleashed on the environment, and if you
> want to end it, you need to cast dispel magic on it.