# Mage Slayer saving throw advantage vs Web spell

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, environmental-hazards

So the Mage Slayer feat says:

> You have advantage on saving throws against spells cast by creatures within 5 feet of you

If a caster were to use web on a Mage Slayer user, does the Mage Slayer have advantage on the Web saving throw at the beginning of their turn if the caster is within 5 feet of them, or does the Web now count as sort of an environmental hazard, and not a "spell cast by a creature"?

[This](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/180510/mage-slayer-advantage-vs-non-instantaneous-spells) thread seems to imply that the Mage Slayer DOES get advantage, but the answer doesn't specifically mention Web, and the idea that using your strength to escape the web is somehow easier because the caster is nearby just doesn't make intuitive sense to me.

Answer (score 17):

[Mage Slayer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/mage-slayer) Feat states that you have an advantage. So you do. [There are no hidden rules.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/196993/10642)

**However** strength check to break free from [Web](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/Web) is a strength check. It's not called a saving throw, so it isn't. Only dexterity saving throw is a saving throw in this spell — because only it is named a saving throw in the spell description. Again, there are no secret rules.

If you need an in-world explanation, extrapolate from the first sentence of the feat:

> You have practiced techniques in melee combat against spellcasters

Maybe you can observe spellcasters to gain intuitive understanding of weaknesses of their spells? Maybe it's the hatred that fuels you? Maybe ancient rituals during training made spells stick to you less? Whatever story you want to tell, you can. As long as the DM is okay with it, of course.

---

For the dillema, is the 5ft at the moment of casting, or at the moment the save is made, I believe that *"spells **cast** by creatures within 5 feet of you.*" means it should be measured at the time of casting the spell. This feat isn't very powerful, however. Guides rate it B or C tier ([example](https://arcaneeye.com/dnd-feat-guides/mage-slayer-5e/)). Thus, personally I would rule to allow both interpretations and grant advantage if either is true. I don't see it making this feat overpowered. Most of the saves are made at the time of casting anyway, and making sub-optimal feat a bit more useful in edge cases won't ruin your game.

Comment: Thank you! That clears things up, I should've noticed that it was a _check_ and not a _save_, and "there are no hidden rules" seems like a good rule of thumb.

Comment: @Thomas a rule that lead designer told us to use. It wasn't official D&D communique, but I think we can trust him on that ;)

Comment: @Mołot This is now a finished answer. +1