# Should dismissing a Blood Hunter's Brand of Castigation require any action?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, blood-hunter

Matt Mercer's Blood Hunter class's [Brand of Castigation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/blood-hunter#BrandofCastigation-1610903) feature specifies that it does *not* require an action to apply the brand, but it doesn't specify whether it requires any action to dismiss it.

The Brand of Castigation feature's description, with my emphasis on the point of contention, is:

> At 6th level, whenever you damage a creature with your Crimson Rite feature, you can choose to sear an arcane brand of hemocraft magic into it (requires no action). You always know the direction to the branded creature, and each time the branded creature deals damage to you or a creature you can see within 5 feet of you, the creature takes psychic damage equal to your Intelligence modifier (minimum of 1 damage).
>
> **Your brand lasts until you dismiss it**, or you apply a brand to another creature. Your brand counts as a spell for the purposes of dispel magic, and the spell level is equal to half of your blood hunter level (maximum of 9th level spell).
>
> Once you use this feature, you can’t use it again until you finish a short or long rest.

Given that it requires no action to *apply* a Brand of Castigation, I would assume that it would similarly require no action or bonus action to *dismiss* it, but I'm unsure how this should be ruled.

I'm aware that [concentration spells can be dismissed at will](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/153443/64466), but this isn't a spell and also does not require concentration to maintain.

Should the Brand of Castigation feature require an action or bonus action to dismiss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### When dismissal requires an action, the feature description tells you.

There is a plethora of examples, but let's consider *mage armor*:

> The spell ends if the target dons armor or *if you dismiss the spell as an action.*

We know that it requires an action to dismiss *mage armor* because the description says it requires an action. If a feature description does not specify, we must assume that there is no action economy cost for dismissal.

Now, some features explain further that no action is required, such as the Robe of Serpents:

> The snake disappears in a harmless puff of smoke after 1 hour, when it drops to 0 hit points, or when you dismiss it (no action required).

But this should be seen as further clarification that no action is required. The robe summons a snake, *and dismissing summoned creatures usually costs an action*, so this feature is clarifying that this time, the summoned creature can be dismissed for free.