# Can a caster end a spell with no concentration, such as "Seeming", whenever they like?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, duration

The player handbook states that a spell that is being concentrated on can be ended with no action, (player handbook page 203) but it doesn't say anything about spells that do not have concentration.

So could spells like Seeming that have a long duration but no concentration also be ended with no action?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate as it clearly meets our [three duplicate criteria](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7524/62294).

Answer (score 10):

### They can for a bunch of spells including Seeming, but this requires an action and does not work for *any* spell

There is no general rule about ending spells which do not require concentration:

> If the spell is not a concentration spell, you can end it early if the spell description says so, but there is no general rule allowing non-concentration spells to be ended early.

See more details in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/153443/27377).

[Seeming](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/seeming) specifically can be dismissed using an action, since its description says so:

> The spell lasts for the duration, unless you use your action to dismiss it sooner.

Many other spells (e.g. [Mage Hand](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mage-hand)) have the same phrasing and can be dismissed using an action. However, there are spells which have not (e.g. [Grease](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/grease)). If nothing says you can end a spell prematurely, then you can't.