# Can you cancel Demiplane at will?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, duration

I have been wondering about this for a while now.
When I cast Demiplane and for example trick a bandit into entering the door, can I then cancel the spells effect and remove the door, trapping the bandit?
Or does it stay there until the hour is over?

> Duration: 1 hour

The description isn't super clear on this aside from the time limit shown.

> When the spell ends, the door disappears, and any creatures or objects inside the demiplane remain trapped there, as the door also disappears from the other side.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Related: [Can I get trapped in my own Demiplane?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71864/52137), [Can you end your own spell prematurely?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/153440/52137)

Comment: Related on [Are non concentration spells dismissable?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/39679/are-non-concentration-spells-dismissable)

Comment: Would like to encourage @kviiri to cross-post [their answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/153443/23547) to [Can you end your own spell prematurely?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/153440/23547) here.

Comment: @NautArch That link is to D&D Next playtest.  I think Someone_Evil's second link is more appropriate for this question's tag.

Comment: @Kirt Still related, the test didn’t change to make a real difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you cannot end the effect of Demiplane early.

It is not a concentration spell, so you can't just stop concentrating to drop the effect.  No part of its effect allows it to end prematurely at-will, either.

You'd need to either ensure the bandit is inside the demiplane when the spell expires.  There are a lot of tools at your disposal to trick or ensnare the bandit to accomplish this task.

Comment: It's not the at-will standard the OP was after, but *Dispel* could potentially be used to end *Demiplane* early.

Comment: @Upper_Case i'll see how it will work out with the Dispel, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 6):

You can end [Demiplane](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/demiplane)'s doorway early if you cast an appropriate spell to cancel an 8th level spell, or can create another effect that is able to suppress magic, for example:

- [Dispel Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic) (contested against 8th Level Spell or 9th Level Spell)
- [Antimagic Field](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field) (Spell)
- Dead Magic Zone (example: Wild Magic)
- Beholder's Gaze (Main Eye)

If you could end a spell at will the spell would be listed as “Up to (#) (Duration)” or it would specify so in the spell description.

Answer (score 0):

The [Demiplane](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/demiplane) spell doesn't mention that it may be dismissed in any way *on its own*, so *on it own* it will last for its full duration.

If you wish to close the door prematurely, you can use [Dispel Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic), as the open door to the Demiplane can count as either a magical object or a magical effect.